# How to let Emacs open and display a file in directory /storage/emulated/0/?

Tags: storage, file-permissions, text-editor

I am using Samsung Galaxy S10+ on Android 12. From F-Droid, I have downloaded and installed Emacs. It can run directly on Android, not via Termux. In the internal storage of my phone, I have created a file `/storage/emulated/0/WE_test01.txt`. By using the X-plore text editor, I have written 2 lines:

```
asd
123
```

Then, this file is to be opened by Emacs. I hit on the Emacs icon and typed <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>f</kbd>, and in the bottom line `/storage/emulated/0/WE_test01.txt`.

The response of Emacs is

> File is not readable

What have I done wrong?

Comment: When talking about third party apps please always include the link to the app in the store you got it from.

Comment: Looks like the screenshot images are not posted or linked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. There are, according to the SourceForge [repo's FAQ](https://sourceforge.net/projects/android-ports-for-gnu-emacs/files/), 3 ways. Since I wanted to use the full disk, I utilized [Special app access](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting-special):

Settings -> Apps -> `...` menu -> Special access -> All files access -> Emacs (toggle)

If you want to allow only specific locations, use this interactive func:

```
M-x android-request-directory-access
```

Also, if you feel comfortable installing it / have means to verify its integrity, install the APK from SourceForge because it has GnuTLS unlike the one from F-Droid (which has none, zero, **plain HTTP**, iirc but feel free to correct me).